# i need more explanation about echo -n "" > file.txt

Tags: bash, echo

I need to know the meaning of `echo -n` and this is example: `echo -n  "" > file.txt`. What is the difference between `echo` and `echo -n` ?

I read `man echo` but need more info.

Comment: The man page is pretty straightforward. Which part of "Do not print the trailing newline character" is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uecho.htm):

> -n : Do not output a trailing newline.

The `>` means write it to a file named `file.txt` (create if doesn't exist).